# How to use fonts for the list items in the getView method

Tags: android, listview, exception

I tried many times and many solutions but every time I found exception or any other error that either not applying fonts or giving me native type cannot be made eror.
I have given my code below please tell me what I am doing wrong:

```
    public class AttractionsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

        private List<Attractions> mENList;
        private int mResource;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        Typeface headingStyle ;
        Typeface contentStyle ;

public AttractionsAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Attractions>       objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);

      mResource = resource;
      mENList = objects;
      inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            //Setting styles for the list items..
            headingStyle = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Attr_List_heading.ttf");
            contentStyle = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Attr_Content.ttf");`
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if(convertView == null){

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, null);

   holder.mTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.heading_1);
   holder.mSummary = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.summary_1);

                holder.mTitle.setTypeface(headingStyle);
                holder.mSummary.setTypeface(contentStyle);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
```

Comment: I am facing this exception:

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
 at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:175)
 at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)

Comment: Where you have added fonts in Asset folder?

Comment: my fonts are in android studio app/asset/fonts folder

Comment: @BilalHussain try placing the files in app/src/main/assets/fonts

Comment: there is no src folder in my android studio I have following folders in my app folder :

Comment: java , manifests , Res, and assets

Comment: Are you using eclipse or studio ?

Comment: I am using android studio

Answer (score 1):

Now, your code assume that fonts are located `/assets` directory.In really, your put all fonts in `/assets/fonts/yourfont.ttf`.You should be like this,

```
 headingStyle = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Attr_List_heading.ttf");
 contentStyle = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Attr_Content.ttf");
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Why you use "fonts/Attr_List_heading.ttf" like that? because I am also using fonts in other activity (but not in the list)  and it works perfectly fine like that "Attr_List_heading.ttf"..

Comment: Now my exception is gone but I dont know why